# Parsing error after editing Asp.Net User Control markup

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have an asp.net webforms (.Net 4.0, Visual Studio 2013) user control which works perfectly right now.  It uses asp label controls and resource tags to bring the text in based on the current user's language/culture setting.

I need to add some text to it.

However, adding a new asp label automatically creates a parsing error.  Once the error has appear, I cannot just delete the label.  I have to revert my markup and designer code back to my last commit.  It seems to me that something must be corrupted in the designer code, but I have no idea where to start looking.

Below is the parsing error:

```
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'OnlineRegistration.Confirmation'.

Source Error:


Line 1:  
Line 2:  <%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Confirmation.ascx.vb" Inherits="OnlineRegistration.Confirmation" %>
Line 3:     
Line 4:      <asp:Label 


Source File: /WebPages/ConfirmationUCTL/Confirmation.ascx    Line: 2
```

Here is the markup of the user control

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Confirmation.ascx.vb" Inherits="OnlineRegistration.Confirmation" %>

    <asp:Label 
        ID="litConfirmation" 
        runat="server" 
        meta:resourcekey="litConfirmationResource1"/>

    <p>
        <asp:Label 
            ID="litConfirmationThankYou" 
            runat="server" 
            meta:resourcekey="litConfirmationThankYouResource1"/>

           <strong>&nbsp
            <asp:Label 
                ID="litConfirmationNumber" 
                runat="server" 
                meta:resourcekey="litConfirmationNumberResource1"/>
        </strong>.&nbsp

          <asp:Label 
            ID="litConfirmationProcessing" 
            runat="server" 
            meta:resourcekey="litConfirmationProcessingResource1"/>
    </p>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" />                  
    <p>
        <asp:Label 
            ID="litConfirmationVNC" 
            runat="server" 
            meta:resourcekey="litConfirmationVNCResource1"/>
    </p>               

    <p>
        <asp:Label 
            ID="litConfirmationQuestions" 
            runat="server" 
            meta:resourcekey="litConfirmationQuestionsResource1"/>
    </p>

    <p>
        <asp:Label 
            ID="litErrorSaving" 
            runat="server" 
            meta:resourcekey="litErrorSavingResource1" 
            CssClass="hide"/>
    </p>

    <asp:HyperLink 
            ID="linkPrintVRA" 
            runat="server" 
            meta:resourcekey="linkPrintVRAResource1" 
            CssClass="hide"/>
```

All I do is add this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" />
```

and then compile and run.  And the parsing error appears.

Any idea where to start looking for this bug?

Comment: check this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7ad2acb0-42ca-4ee8-9161-681689b60dda/bin-folder-location-causes-parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-problem?forum=winformssetup

Comment: thanks for the link.  But this is on my development box and I've checked all the references.  So it doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: I have seen suggestions to use CodeFile instead of CodeBehind, and also clear the bin folder. You need to try few things, this seems to be a bug

Comment: I have cleared out the bin file.  But CodeFile isn't an option because it's not precompiled code and thus the source file sites on the server.  It's against our security policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know WHY this happened.  But I went with the theory that somehow the designer.vb file was corrupt.

So I copied the contents of the markup and code behind file into a text file.

Then I deleted the whole user control from the project and saved and cleaned the application.

Then I added the user control back in from scratch and saved.

Finally, I copied the contents of the markup and code behind back into the user control, saved and compiled.

Now adding new controls to the markup is working fine.